# How to prevent Motorola Cliq from factory reset upon startup?

Tags: factory-reset, motorola

I have a Cliq (MB200) which I successfully rooted. I would like to permanently disable the Motoblur application which always appears at startup. Until now I've been using the "#eebluroff" code to temporarily disable it, but this causes an automatic factory reset the next time the phone is rebooted. There must be some way to prevent this from happening... any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried using an alternative Launcher app ?

Comment: I'm rather new to this, could you explain please?

Comment: Android Launchers are applications that are responsible for the User Interface of the Android Home Screen and the App Drawer. Most manufacturers customize this part of Android to differentiate their UI from other OEMs. motoblur is one such Launcher Application. You can download another Launcher from the Play Store and set it as the default launcher.

Comment: I suspect it wouldn't help, because the next time I reboot, it will automatically reset and delete the launcher! Might there be some kind of editable startup file that contains a switch that triggers the reset?

Comment: From what I understand you have this issue of resetting when you use the "#eebluroff" code, right ?

Comment: Correct. I am forced to use the code because otherwise the Motoblur software locks me out entirely. (Catch-22...)

Comment: Since extended discussions are not recommended in the comments session, I will do some research and get back to you as soon as I can.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15531/discussion-between-john-s-perayil-and-kurkevan).